# Is there a way to tag contacts when report is sent?

Tags: civireport

When a report is sent, can I automatically add a tag to the contacts that are in the report?

This report concerns a group of contacts that are in a smart group and after the e-mail is sent, I'll love to remove them out of this smart group according to this tag.

Is this possible?

Comment: if it is possible it would probably require civirules but i suspect 'sending a report' is unlikely to be an available trigger

Comment: there is no such trigger :-( I'm trying a different way